# how to insert data with ajax and php without page refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I real need your help since I'm a beginner in php and Ajax. My problem is that, I can not send data in the database via my appended form in **post.php,** also when the button of id **#reply** clicked it sends empty data to database by refreshing the page. When the reply link is pressed I only get the Result of reply link to be shown without other information (name and comment). I need your help to make my appanded form to be able to add/send data to the database without refreshing the page, I also need to disable the form from **index.php** to make replies when the reply button / link is pressed. Thank you.

***post.php***

```
<?php      include("config.php"); //inserting
$action=$_POST["action"];
 if($action=="addcomment"){
      $author = $_POST['name'];
      $comment_body = $_POST['comment_body'];
      $parent_id = $_POST['parent_id'];
  $q = "INSERT INTO nested (author, comment, parent_id) VALUES ('$author', '$comment_body', $parent_id)";
  $r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)==1) { header("location:index.php");}
else { }
}   
// showing data  
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); 
function getComments($conn, $row) {
$action=$_POST["action"];
 if($action=="showcomment"){  $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<li class='comment'><div class='aut'>".$row['author']."</div><div class='comment-body'>".$row['comment']."</div>";
    echo "<a href='#comment_fo' class='reply' id='".$row['id']."'>Reply</a>";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `nested` WHERE parent_id = '$id' ORDER BY `id` DESC"); 
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { getComments($conn,$row);        }
      echo "</ul>"; } echo "</li>";
}   
 if($action=="showcomment"){
$q = "SELECT * FROM nested WHERE parent_id = '".$row['id']."' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ getComments($conn,$row); }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><head><script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.reply").one("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var parent = $(this).parent();
      $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
parent.append(" <br /><div id='form'><form><input type='text' name='name' id='name'><textarea name='comment_body' id='comment_body'></textarea><input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'><button id='reply'>Reply</button></form></div>");  
     $("#reply").click(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var comment_body=$("#comment_body").val();
        var parent_id=$("#parent_id").val();
           $.ajax({
                 type:"post",
                 url:"post.php",
                 data:"name="+name+"&comment_body="+comment_body+"&parent_id="+parent_id+"&action=addcomment",
                    success:function(data){ showComment(); }
                 });
              });
     });        
 });
 </script></head></html>
```

***//index.php***

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showComment(){
    $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"post.php",
       data:"action=showcomment",
           success:function(data){ $("#comment").html(data); }
         });
   }
  showComment();
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function(){
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var comment_body=$("#comment_body").val();
        var parent_id=$("#parent_id").val();
           $.ajax({
                 type:"post",
                 url:"post.php",
                 data:"name="+name+"&comment_body="+comment_body+"&parent_id="+parent_id+"&action=addcomment",
                    success:function(data){
                 showComment();             
                     }
                 });
             });
});
</script></head><body>
<form id="form_comment">
  <input type="text" name="name" id='name'/>
  <textarea name="comment_body" id='comment_body'></textarea>
  <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'/>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Comment"/>
</form>
<div id="comment"></div> </body></html>
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Before continuing with this you should learn about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), prepared statements and how to [filter user input](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php).

Comment: Its true, Thank your advice. JasonBoss. But, please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();  //add this line to prevent reload
      var name=$("#name").val();
      var comment_body=$("#comment_body").val();
      var parent_id=$("#parent_id").val();
      $.ajax({
             type:"post",
             url:"post.php",
             data:"name="+name+"&comment_body="+comment_body+"&parent_id="+parent_id+"&action=addcomment",
                success:function(data){
             showComment();             
                 }
             });
         });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, But how about  $("#reply").click(function(){ } ? because I'm having problem there

Comment: same put $("#reply").click(function(e){  e.preventDefault(); }

Comment: I did it to both pages tp prevent the default submission, but nothing has changed, Im still getting null results, I mean the comment work perfect, but the problem is on repy form

Comment: Try alert(name + comment_body + parent_id)  before your ajax call if you will get any value

Comment: any feedback? are you getting any alert?

Comment: I did that, But I only get the reply ID of the comment. The ajax script used to post reply are the same as the comment script except the Id of their button. But why It did not add the data like the way I expected? .

Comment: Yes I get the alert with only reply Id shown. nothing else display. On the alert "102"

Comment: meaning the value of name and comment is empty.

Comment: Yes your right, that is only exactly I get empy value  Genina.

Comment: check your console tab f12 "Element" then check your inputs if you are passing any value.

Comment: I checked the console works fast when I make a comment, but when I tried to make a reply the page take long time to load until i pressed the Ok btn of the alert.. also on the url bar displayed localhost/myfile/?name=sssss&comment_body=dddddd&parent_id=0#reply

Comment: check your input field <input type=text name="comment_body" id="comment_body" value="ddddd"> if there's is value before you reply. I think it doesn't have any value.

Comment: Yes, my input's do not hold any value. sometime when I commented, and trying to make reply through reply form the reply form add the value like the posted comment

Comment: Can you tell me the process of your comment and reply? on how you will get any value for your inputs?

Comment: when  i commented and press the reply and fill in the reply form and pressing the reply button, the same value i.e fi the comment is "me" also the reply will be "me"

Comment: my db has id, author,,comment,parent_id

Comment: <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='0'> try to change the id of this and try to alert again i think you are not getting you input fields

Comment: By making comment using the form on index.php It make the comment well without page being refreshed, sometime if I make reply using the form from index it did fine.But, that is not what i want, I need the reply form to be displayed below the particular comment when the reply lick has been clicked. Thus why I tried to append the form with the same as  the form of index.php except their button IDs.

Comment: i see you are appending inputs without value. So expect it you will not get any value.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Genina.. Also when I Checked in alert I think I'm getting the value of the  "<a href='#form' class='reply' id='".$row['id']."'>Reply</a>"

Comment: So, what can I do to make it function?

Comment: Yes, with all my efforts!  Please help me to append well my reply form to make it functioning..

Comment: try to <a href='#form' class='reply' id='".$row['id']."'>Reply</a>" add here like data='".$row['comment_body']."'

Comment: When I tried that, no reply added, or no  data shown on alert

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple **incomplete** ajax example.

### FromPage.php

Here is the ajax that I'd use. The variables can be set however you like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
        var name = "John Smith";

        $.ajax({
                url: 'toDB.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                        carArray: cars, 
                        firstName: name 
                },
                success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data); //Testing
                }
        });

</script>
```

---

### toDB.ph

This is the second page - the one that writes the values to the database etc.

```
<?php
    $cars = $_POST['carArray'];
    $FirstName=$_POST['firstName'];

    //Used to test - it will print out the array
    print("<pre>");
    print_r($cars);
    print("</pre>");

    //Do something with $cars array and $FirstName variable
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. All you can see I'm trying to call the form from the file that arleady called via ajax, So, I want to make it function by sending data to the database using the appended form in post.php