# Inserting through AJAX page is refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Inserting the data through AJAX it's working but pages refreshing, why is that give a feedback to fix this issues.

This is my ajax code

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){

                var postId=$("#postId").val();
                var userId=$("#userId").val();
                var postComm=$("#postComments").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'../validate/inserPostComm.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        poId:postId,
                        usId:userId,
                        poco:postComm
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       //alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here I'm using HTML

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="postId" name="postId" value="<?php echo $_GET["postId"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["u_id"]; ?>">
<textarea placeholder="Post your comment" id="postComments"></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Change the type of **button** from `submit` to `button`

Comment: is this referencing the same file?

Comment: Yes it's refreshing the same file..

Comment: I don't get why people are down-voting this post. It's a perfectly legitimate question that catches a lot of new people off guard because it's not an obvious solution.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759380/how-to-stop-refreshing-page-after-ajax-call and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475937/how-to-insert-data-with-ajax-and-php-without-page-refresh and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651947/insert-into-mysql-database-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix: Add a preventDefault(). Notice the 'e' I added to your click function.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();

                var postId=$("#postId").val();
                var userId=$("#userId").val();
                var postComm=$("#postComments").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'../validate/inserPostComm.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        poId:postId,
                        usId:userId,
                        poco:postComm
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       //alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This will work, also mention changing input type submit to button. :)

Comment: As a matter of practice, I do this with every button event listener whether it's submit or not. Just a little extra insurance.

Comment: It's Working and same like i'm using another ajax code that also same the pages is refreshing.

Comment: @Difster yeah that's.

Answer (score 5):

You are facing it due to the button having input type “Submit”

```
<button type="submit" id="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
```

Just change it to normal “button”

```
<button type="button " id="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
```

Comment: exactly type="submit" was the issue, vote up from me

Answer (score 0):

another ajax i'm using but some issue is coming page is refreshing.

```
<script>
    function inspire(x){
        var insPer =$("#insPer"+x).val();
        var insPos =$("#insPos"+x).val();


        $.ajax({
            url:'../validate/inspire.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                u_id:insPer,
                p_id:insPos
            },
           success:function(data){
               //alert(data);
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```

this is html code

```
<input type="hidden" id="insPer<?php echo $p_id; ?>" name="insPer" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["u_id"]; ?>"> 

<input type="hidden" id="insPos<?php echo $p_id; ?>" name="insPos" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>">

<a href="#" onclick="inspire(<?php echo $p_id; ?>);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default submit button behavior - submitting the form - with `event.preventDefault();`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(event){
            // prevent the default submit button behaviour
            event.preventDefault();
            var postId=$("#postId").val();
            var userId=$("#userId").val();
            var postComm=$("#postComments").val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'../validate/inserPostComm.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    poId:postId,
                    usId:userId,
                    poco:postComm
                },
               success:function(data){
                   //alert(data);
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better do this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("form#comment").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
              var formData = new FormData(this);
              // console.log(formData);
              $.ajax({
                  url: '../validate/inserPostComm.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: formData, //The Form data contain array (postId,userId,postComments)
                  success: function (data) {
                      // do something if success
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                      //If error thrown here
                  }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="comment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="postId" name="postId" value="...">
<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="...">
<textarea placeholder="Post your comment" id="postComments" name="postComments"></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```